# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'web/static/js/app' from '/'

Tags: vue.js, phoenix-framework, elixir

When trying to follow this tutorial : [Chat web-app using Phoenix and Vue.js — Part 1](https://medium.com/@jespr/create-a-simple-chat-web-app-using-phoenix-and-vue-js-bc5d82e53f9b?fbclid=IwAR38QqXuBZd1V-04PPrA2sEOMPAEhetf2YgEVFMzzVUP_7vWMkjvAeeJtdQ), I'm stuck where I should see this message in the browser console

> Joined successfully Object {**ob**: Observer}

I have follow every single instructions:

- Time to create the Phoenix project : **SUCCESS**
- Let’s integrate Vue.js : **SUCCESS**
- Time to initialize the Vue app and create our first component : **SUCCESS**
- Vue.js and Phoenix sitting in a tree.. Time to hook these two up!: **Whenever I run this command, I get**

> app.js:61 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'web/static/js/app' from
>   '/'
>       at require (app.js:61)
>       at browser.js:190

I have tried everything I found on internet but still not able to do it

Below are my code and file location in the project:

**web/static/app.js**

```
import "phoenix_html"
import socket from "/js/socket"
```

**web/static/js/socket.js**

```
import {Socket} from "phoenix"
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyApp from "../components/my-app.vue"

let socket = new Socket("/socket", {params: {token: window.userToken}})
socket.connect()

// Create the main component
Vue.component('my-app', MyApp)

// And create the top-level view model:
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement(MyApp, {})
  }
});
```

**web/channels/room_channel.ex**

```
defmodule Vuechat.RoomChannel do
    use Vuechat.Web, :channel

    def join("room:lobby", payload, socket) do
        {:ok, socket}
    end

    def join("room:" <> _private_room_id, _params, _socket) do
        {:error, %{reason: "Unauthorized"}}
    end

    def handle_in("new_msg", %{"body" => body}, socket) do
        broadcast! socket, "new_msg", %{body: body}
        {:noreply, socket}
    end

    def handle_out("new_msg", payload, socket) do
        push socket, "new_msg", payload
        {:noreply, socket}
    end
end
```

Does anyone have a solution on this ?

Comment: The error message says you are expecting **app.js** in **web/static/js/app**, but yours seems to be in **web/static/app.js**. Try moving the file to the /js/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps you but I could not comment.

You may have forgotten to run these commands:

```
npm install --save vue vue-router
npm install --save-dev vue-brunch babel-plugin-transform-runtime
```

Unless you don't install above dependencies the error will be the same as yours.